# Close form to polynomial times Gaussian sum $\displaystyle\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}} m^{2k} e^{-m^2}, \ k \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$

Tags: summation, special-functions

Is there a closed form to the sum:$\displaystyle\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}} m^{2k} e^{-m^2}, \ k \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$?

Thanks!

Comment: It is the $k$-th derivative of the special function $\Theta(x)=\sum_m e^{-m^2\pi x}$ at $x=1/\pi$. Zero chance that it simplifies. At $x=1$, maybe.

Comment: Thanks! I have noticed that it was the kth derivative of the theta function, I was hoping if there is a simpler form.